# filter para obtener los registro contenidos de una lista Django?

Tags: django, django-models

espero que no sea un poco trivial mi pregunta tengo los siguientes modelos.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     tipo= UCharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class  ModelB(models.Model):
     model_a= models.ForeignKey(ModelA, null=False, blank=False,related_name='modelA_%(class)s_objects')
```

Requiero obtener los registros contenidos en el siguiente array:

```
list_id= list(ModelA.objects.filter(tipo= 1).values_list('id', flat=True)) 
ModelB.objects.filter(modal_a_id__in = list_id)
```

Resulta que “IN” devuelve si encontró alguno de los valores del array, requiero que arroje resultados cuando todos los ids del arreglo estén contenidos en el modelo ModelB.
Bien podría hacer una iteración por cada valor en el arreglo y revisar si existe, alguna sugerencia para hacerlo de una manera más simple??

Comment: No comprendo bien que quieres hacer, es como decir que deben existir x numeros de objetos con ModelA, y esa misma cantidad de objetos para ModelB?

Comment: Si, obtengo una conjunto de objetos del ModelA una lista de Ids [1,2,3], y quiero consultar que esos objetos esten en el ModelB , y que solo me arroje resultados el ModelB si los encontro todos. (espero me explique).

Comment: ¿¿es decir, podria servirte algo como esto??, seguro no es la respuesta, pero es lo que necesitas, así sabre como plantear mejor la respuesta... si tienes la lista de ids `l = [1,2,3]` entonces hacer un queryset asi `ModelB.objects.filter(modal_a_id__in=l).values_list('modal_a__id', flat=True) == l`, es eso lo que neesitas??, para evaluarlo de otra forma de hacerlo en un queryset sin necesidad de recorrerlo...

Comment: Gracias , no es lo que busco , ya que "modal_a_id__in=l" retornara datos si alguno de los valores de "l" se encuentra. Pero requiero que retorne valor si todos los valores de "l" los encontro. Implementar un queryset para no recorrerlo y revisar que todos existan.

Comment: ok, no se si notaste que al final puse un `== l`, que significa que sí encontró tal cual lo que le mandaste a buscar (hay que agregarle un distinct al queryset para que funcione adecuadamente)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
list_id = get_objcet_or_404(ModelA, tipo=self.kwargs['....']
modelob = ModelB.objects.filter(modal_a = list_id)
return modelob
```

el `kwargs` lo agregas a los urls como patterns y te hará el filtrado por lista

otra opción sería:

```
def get_queryset(self):
if self.kwarg.get('....'):
queryset = self.model.objects.filter(model_a__tipo=self.kwargs['....'])
else:
queryset = super(NOMBRE DE LA CLASE DE LA VISTA, self).get_queryset
return queryset
```

Espero que te sirva y solucionar tu duda, saludos, se me olvidaba. en la segunda opción tienes que agregar el `field` en el caso de que no haya nada :

```
model = ModelB
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

list_id= list(ModelA.objects.filter(tipo= 1).values_list('id', flat=True)) 
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(model_a=id) for id in list_id))
result = ModelB.objects.filter(query)
```